# jQuery TableSorter Plugin: Does Pager addon support internationalization?

Tags: jquery, internationalization, tablesorter

I am using jQuery TableSorter plugin (http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/ *a fork of TableSorter plugin (http://tablesorter.com) by* @Mottie) for tables; and since my website supports multiple languages, I have to provide translation for its Pager addon.

Did anyone try to internationalize it?

I have browsed its website and searched the web with no luck.

Any help would be appreciated!

**Update:** *@Mottie, thank you for providing an output option.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like Pager addon had only one line to translate, which can be supplied while initializing the addon.

```
$('.transactions')
   .tablesorter({
        theme : 'blue',
        widgets: [ "zebra", "resizable" ],
        widgetOptions: {
          resizable : true,
          resizable_widths : [ '40px', '100px', '100px' ]
        }
    })
    .tablesorterPager({
          container: $("#pager"), 
          output: 'с {startRow} по {endRow} из {totalRows} транзакции'} //<-- this line
          //output: "{startRow} to {endRow} of {totalRows} rows" //<-- original
    );
```

This is fine for me.

Comment: Please note that the code above only applies to my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) and not the original tablesorter (link shared in the question). The original does not work with the resizable widget and does not include the pager output option.